# Django form inside a page which is a form too

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

Help please,

I have my RaodNetwork model  which hold the Project model as Foreign Key. I Would like :

1 - One we are inside a project, select automatically the foreign key of this project without no
ned to select it manually

2 - to create a road network instance and display (add) it inside a project.
Here is my project page (pk=1) with my roadnetwork instance

[image: here is my project page (pk=1) with my roadnetwork instance]

views.py

```
def create_network(request, pk):
    """A roadnetwork depends on a project. It
     must be created inside the project"""

    project = Project.objects.get(id=pk)
    form = RoadNetworkForm(initial={'project':project})
    if request.method =='POST':
        form=RoadNetworkForm(request.POST, instance=project)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('home')

    context = {'form':form}
    return render(request, 'roadnetwork.html', context)


class RoadNetwork(models.Model):
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    simple = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    locked = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    #representation = path
    nb_nodes = models.IntegerField()
    nb_edges = models.IntegerField()
    name = models.CharField('Network Name', max_length=200, blank=False)
    comment = models.TextField()
    tags = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return "{}".format(self.name)


class Project(models.Model):
    owner = models.ManyToManyField(User) # define as FK and add a user as ManyToManyField
    public = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    name = models.CharField('Project Name', max_length=200, null=False)
    comment = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return "{}".format(self.name)


urlpatterns=[
    path('project/<str:pk>/', project_pagination, name = 'project'),
    path('network/<str:pk>/', create_network, name = 'create_network'),
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the `instance` parameter of your ModelForm incorrectly. You are supposed to provide a `RoadNetwork` object there since you want to save one. If you want to create a new one, first create it, then pass it to the Form. This way, you can provide values which were not submitted in the form. See this edited version of your view:

```py
def create_network(request, pk):
    """A roadnetwork depends on a project. It
     must be created inside the project"""

    current_project = Project.objects.get(id=pk)
    form = RoadNetworkForm(initial={'project':project})
    if request.method =='POST':
        network = RoadNetwork(project=current_project)
        form=RoadNetworkForm(request.POST, instance=network)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('home')

    context = {'form':form}
    return render(request, 'roadnetwork.html', context)
```

For clarity as to which `project` is which, I have replaced the `project` variable with `current_project`. `project` in the `RoadNetwork` class call refers to its `project` field.

Some other suggestions: Use a `try...except` block for cases when `pk` does not exist. `Project.objects.get(pk=pk)` will throw a `Project.DoesNotExist` exception if it can’t find anything.

Comment: It works fine. Lots of thanls for your help and suggestions.